# CastleWindsor, Generic Repository and two database contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, castle-windsor

I have two separate databases for storing documents and users. Also I've implemented generic repository pattern:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public DbContext Context { get; set; }

        public Repository()
        {

        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return Context.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsEnumerable();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            Context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }


        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that entities are stored in different DbContexts and I can't use something like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>));
```

How can I specify which DbContext should be used for each entity?
For example, if I want create Repository that means that one database should be used, but if I want Repository another context should be used.
Or I should create two repo classes, like this:

```
public class AttachmetRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public AttachmetsDbContext Context { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class UserRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public UsersDbContext Context { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

The reason why I don't want to use two different repositories is to keep services simple, something like this:

```
 public class SomeService: ISomeService
    {
        public IRepository<User> UserRepository { get; set; } //database 1
        public IRepository<Comment> CommentsRepository { get; set; } //database 1
        public IRepository<Attachment> AttachmentRepository { get; set; } //database 2
        ...
}
```

**UPD:**
As Ognyan suggested I've used FactoryMethod and this helped! Thanks a lot, Ognyan!
I'm new to CastleWindsor and I'm not sure its the best and fastest way, but here is my code:

```
public class EFDatabaseInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<AttContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
            container.Register(Component.For<DefContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, context) =>
            {
                var genericType = context.RequestedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                Type type = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);
                object repository = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                PropertyInfo dbContextProperty = type.GetProperty("Context");

                if (genericType == typeof(Attachment))
                {
                    dbContextProperty.SetValue(repository, kernel.Resolve<AttContext>());
                }
                else
                {
                    dbContextProperty.SetValue(repository, kernel.Resolve<DefContext>());
                }

                return repository;
            }).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need not to hard code the DbContext inside the repository. You can remake your repository like this :

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    // you can even make it IDbContextProvider with .Current() method in order not
    // to place a hard dependency but depend on Interface which is the proper way.
    // I was in a hurry and did not want to overcomplicate the implementation.

    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected IDbSet<T> CreateSet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>(); 
    }

    public virtual T Find(int id)
    {
        return CreateSet<T>().Find(id);
    }
... 
}
```

After that you need a factory method and a way to distinguish the destination db. One way to distinguish is to get the info from the CreationContext of the factory method :

```
private static DbContext DbContextFactoryMethod(IKernel k, ComponentModel cm, CreationContext c)
```

Here you can traverse the resolution stack and see if this is part of graph that contains IRepository or other entity and choose your database.

This way you will get the proper DbContext inside your repository without sticking all of them inside which will become more and more cumbersome with time.